# Java: Object as Value in HashMap being overwritten?

Tags: java, hashmap, overwrite

I am adding/editing objects that are values in a hashmap-- with different keys.

However, editing one object in the hashmap seems to edit them all(?)

What am I doing wrong here?

First, my (poorly named) hashmap class:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class hashmap {

static HashMap<Integer, exObj> hm;

hashmap(){
    hm = new HashMap<Integer, exObj>();
}
public void createVal(){
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        hm.put(i, new exObj(i));
    }
    hm.get(2).setValue();
}
public void printVal(){
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(hm.get(i).getValue());
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    hashmap hmap = new hashmap();
    hmap.createVal();
    hmap.printVal();    
}

}
```

Second, my simple exObj Class:

```
public class exObj {

private static int value;

exObj(int i){
    value = i;
}

public void setValue(){
    value = value + 1;
}

public int getValue(){
    return value; 
}

}
```

returns output:

```
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have static data which is shared amongst all instances of a class.

Try changing your class to have instance data (i.e. simply remove the static on `private int value`).

Comment: Since he is using `exObj` only as the value, not as the key, in the `HashMap`, it's not really necessary to override `hashCode` and `equals`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because `value` in your class `exObj` is `static`:

```
public class exObj {

private static int value;
```

Because it is `static`, there is only one copy of the variable, which is shared by all `exObj` objects.

See [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Comment: Got it--I didn't realize all of the objects shared static variables!

Comment: @quannabe That's the point of `static` fields. It's best not to use them with mutable data.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jeff Foster and @Jesper said, it's all about using a static variable. Just to add some more info on your example, by running the code

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
    hm.put(i, new exObj(i));
}
```

the last exObj that gets initialized get the value '9', which is shared for all the instances. Then by calling

```
hm.get(2).setValue();
```

the value is set as '10'

You can simply declare the 'value' as

```
private int value;
```

so every instance of exObj will have it's own value. Also remember to have your Class names starting with a capital letter, as a good practice